# Troubleshooting jmockittomockito plugin

Tags: openrewrite

I am following the instruction here https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/testing/jmockit/jmockittomockito to convert jmockit unit tests to mockito.

But on running 'gradle rewriteRun' , it seems to be stuck and never finish. Is there any logging I can enable or any other troubleshooting steps I can perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last week we fixed an infinite loop that's likely affecting you here:

- https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-testing-frameworks/pull/485

You can try out that fix using version `2.5.0-SNAPSHOT` of `rewrite-testing-frameworks`:

- https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/snapshot-instructions

We'll likely follow up with a release somewhere this week; sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: After using the new version, the infinite loop issue is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear, thanks for confirming!